# How to make a p:carousel item fit the carousel width and height?

Tags: css, primefaces

I have a `p:outputLabel` in a `p:caroussel` which should display its right border to match the caroussel, i.e. at the outside of a 400px x 200px frame:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:panelGroup style="width: 400px; float: left;" layout="block">
        <p:carousel>
        <p:outputLabel value="No preview available" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; display: block;"/>
        </p:carousel>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

It displays the border around an inexplicable frame of 50px x 200px:

[image]

MVCE at https://github.com/krichter722/jsf-width-and-height-on-outputlabel.

I'm using Primefaces 6.0.

Comment: So it works if you remove the `p:panelGroup`? or if you remove the 'block style' on the outputlabel? And look at the client-side generated html... That will with css lead you to the cause... This is 'effectively' not PrimeFaces related but most likely pure html/css (and 100% not jsf-2.2, not even jsf  so I removed that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly simple. Don't bother trying to hack this using CSS, but set the `numVisible` attribute to `1` on your `p:carousel`.

This worked for me:

```
<h:panelGroup style="width: 400px; float: left;" layout="block">
  <p:carousel numVisible="1" itemStyle="height: 200px;">
    <h:outputText value="No preview available"/>
  </p:carousel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Also note that you can use `itemStyle` to set the height of your item (if you need a fixed height).

[image]

...don't mind the cursor ;-)

Comment: This would indeed be the answer if the question contained a [mcve], but I doubt it is since this would be a weird usage of a carousel ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje good point, see https://github.com/krichter722/jsf-width-and-height-on-outputlabel for MCVE. It works, thank you!

Comment: What I meant was **why** would you want to put just an outputlabel (and just 1) in a carousel? It would have been a good addition to your question. Since for the reason that it looked a bit weird, I did not look further and just suggested some things you could investigate. And as a side note, a [mcve] belongs IN stackoverflow, not in an external gitub (for reasons of external code might change/disappear/...